# HTML form Radio button positioning

Tags: html, css

My question is pretty basic. its about the placement of my radio button 
The buttons are slightly below its adjacent text. how to position it exactly in front of its text
Click at the link of sign up form as it provides the image of my problem 
   [sign up form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vc4x.png)

Comment: post your code in jsfiddle or codepen and share its link here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stephennollan/ph6sgnwy/

Comment: srry have never used fidddle before. i made account just now. Is  the link above is wat u were asking?also the result on fiddle is very much different from mine

Comment: yes that's what i was looking for. Check my answer below

Comment: Always post a [mcve] *in your question* before using any third party sites please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this form the radio buttons are exactly before the text
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>






    <form >


    <label>Name</label>

    <input type="text">
    <br>

    <label>Email</label>


    <input type="email" name="">

    <br>
    <label>Date</label>

    <input type="date" name="">

    <br>

    <label>Password</label>

    <input type="password" name="">

    <br>

    <label>Color</label>

    <input type="color" name="">

    <br>
    <label>Select Any One</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="">Travel
    <input type="checkbox" name="">Food

    <input type="checkbox" name="">Hotel


    <br>

    <label>Select Gender</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender">FeMale



    <br>
    <select>
        <option>Select Box</option>
    </select>

    <br>


    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>














    </form>













    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `width:100%` from the following code solved the problem in your jsfiddle

```
*{
margin:0px auto;

}
```

Its because that style was applicable for all the elements the text and radio button was misplaced